# How to trigger a window.scrollTo(x, y) in phantomJS

Tags: javascript, phantomjs

I open a web page, and I want trigger a scrolling in onLoadFinished callback.
but it dose't working. I also tried scrollPosition and set timer to sent key event.
Both of them dose't working.
So ask for help.

```
page.onLoadFinished = function() {
    window.scrollTo(0, document.height);
}

page.open('http://www.XXX.com', function (status) {
    if (status !== 'success') {
        console.log('Unable to open weibo.com');
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you try logging `document.height`?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Why would you need scrolling if you could open the page in the whole size? Just set size of the page to be whatever size you need.

Comment: Because scrolling will trigger a XHR which will pull some data.

Comment: I solved it. set page.viewportSize = { width: 1366, height: bignumber };Set a big number of height will pull all content.

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I suggested, and, what is about your extra data you mentioned?

Comment: The extra data is pulled by the big view size.