# Test scroll position with Karma, PhantomJS, Jasmine

Tags: jasmine, phantomjs, karma-runner

I'm using Karma with Jasmine configured with the PhantomJS browser as detailed in browser section of [Karma's config docs](http://karma-runner.github.io/0.10/config/configuration-file.html).

I'm testing a scroll behavior in the page by inspecting the `$('body,html').scrollTop()` value.

This works fine in Chrome. However, in PhantomJS the window size seems to be growing to be the size of the document. From their docs, working with [viewport](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15752622/281809) and [scrollPosition](http://phantomjs.org/release-1.3.html) requires direct phantomJS WebPage API usage.

Is there a way in Karma spec scripts to access the PhantomJS page object?

Comment: fwiw - i'm now using a [better method for assessing scroll top](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/871399/cross-browser-method-for-detecting-the-scrolltop-of-the-browser-window). But the Phantom issue described is unrelated to this.

Comment: I am having the same issue. I wish there is a settings option for PhantomJS

Answer (score 7):

A Karma contributor basically says in this this [Github Issue](https://github.com/karma-runner/karma-phantomjs-launcher/issues/22) to not use Karma for integration-level tests that would require dealing with the `page` variable.

[vojtajina commented 3 months ago](https://github.com/karma-runner/karma-phantomjs-launcher/issues/22#issuecomment-29539126)

> You can't access `page` variable - the Angular scenario runner tests run IN THE BROWSER and there is no `page` variable.
>
> The `page` variable is available in the phantomjs script (that you write to control the phantomjs browser). If you wanna use PhantomJS and its DSL for writing high level tests, just use PhantomJS without Angular scenario runner.

[vojtajina commented 3 months ago](https://github.com/karma-runner/karma-phantomjs-launcher/issues/22#issuecomment-29589649)

> Nope, just use PhantomJS without Karma. Karma is for unit testing.